# Pub-sub between Elastic Search and Apache Ignite

Tags: elasticsearch, publish-subscribe, ignite

I have implemented a custom CacheStore in Ignite to communicate with Elastic Search. My question is, is there any way to make Ignite get any change that happens  in the Elastic Search DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignite's CacheStore are pull-oriented: they pull data from DB but DB does not push updates to Ignite. This is because most DBs don't have robust update notify mechanism (and in the case of MVCC/SQL transactions this is actually not possible to implement correctly for all cases).

You can try starting Ignite's DataStreamer somewhere on the side of Elasticsearch, push all updates to it. This will require development work, of course.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the DataStreamer implementation part? To be precise, I am not getting a clear picture of how I should attach it to ES.

Comment: If ES has some listener for getting updates, you can hook DataStreamer to it.